# split uint32 value to uint8 values in swift

Tags: swift, type-conversion, uint8t

in C I have

```
uint32 value = 39434;
uint8 firstByte = (unsigned char)value;
uint8 secondByte = (unsigned char)(value >> 8);
```

Is there any possibility to achieve the same in Swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite similar in Swift:

```
let value : UInt32 = 39434
let firstByte = UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: value) // 10
let secondByte = UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: value >> 8) // 154
```

The special initializer `init(truncatingBitPattern:)`
is required here because Swift (in contrast to C), does not implicitly
truncate integers:

```
let firstByte = UInt8(value)
```

would result in a runtime exception if  `value` does not fit into
the range of `UInt8`.

See also [Split UInt32 into [UInt8] in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970204/split-uint32-into-uint8-in-swift)
for possible solutions which give you an *array* with the
four bytes of the input value.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the bitpattern-dedicated initalizer `init(truncatingBitPattern:)` is to manually mask all bytes but the byte of interest, and shift this byte appropriately; followed by using the "standard" `UInt8` value conversion initializer:

```
let val : UInt32 = 39434

let byte1 = UInt8(val & 0x000000FF)         // 10
let byte2 = UInt8((val & 0x0000FF00) >> 8)  // 154
let byte3 = UInt8((val & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) // 0
let byte4 = UInt8((val & 0xFF000000) >> 24) // 0

/* ... */
let val : UInt32 = UINT32_MAX

let byte1 = UInt8(val & 0x000000FF)         // 255
let byte2 = UInt8((val & 0x0000FF00) >> 8)  // 255
let byte3 = UInt8((val & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) // 255
let byte4 = UInt8((val & 0xFF000000) >> 24) // 255
```

Or, to simplify, e.g. as a computed property in an extension

```
extension UInt32 {
    var asByteArray: [UInt8] {
        return [0, 8, 16, 24]
            .map { UInt8(self >> $0 & 0x000000FF) }
    }
}

/* example usage */
val.asByteArray 
    /* [10, 154, 0, 0], 
       [255, 255, 255, 255], for the examples above */
```

This is, however, naturally not as safe as using the dedicated initializer, as it places the responsibility of masking and correct shifting on the developer rather than the compiler. If not taking care, the non-truncated conversion from the four bytes into one will yield a runtime integer overflow.