# How to pack negative Int64 into the byte array

Tags: swift

I have trouble trying to convert Int64 to byte array. App fails when `value` is negative.

This is what I have in my playground:

```
let value: Int64 = -1

let byte1: UInt8 = UInt8((value >> 56) | Int64(0xFF))
let byte2: UInt8 = UInt8((value >> 48) | Int64(0xFF))
let byte3: UInt8 = UInt8((value >> 40) | Int64(0xFF))
let byte4: UInt8 = UInt8((value >> 32) | Int64(0xFF))
let byte5: UInt8 = UInt8((value >> 24) | Int64(0xFF))
let byte6: UInt8 = UInt8((value >> 16) | Int64(0xFF))
let byte7: UInt8 = UInt8((value >> 8) | Int64(0xFF))
let byte8: UInt8 = UInt8(value & Int64(0xFF))
```

I'm not sure (can't check right now) but same code works in the c++-port.

Comment: Why are there `|`'s? Aren't they all supposed to be `&`?

Comment: @harold, ssss-ugar. thank you.

Comment: Simpler solution to get the bytes would just be `Data(bytes: &value, count: MemoryLayout<Int64>.size)` (and make `value` a `var`). If you want an array, wrap it in `Array`'s sequence initialiser.

Comment: Related: [Split UInt32 into [UInt8] in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970204/split-uint32-into-uint8-in-swift) (those solutions should work for signed integers are well).