# Convert UInt32 to 4 bytes Swift

Tags: swift

How do I convert a UInt32 value to 4 bytes in swift?

I have a value of (3) when I get;

IPP_ORIENTATION.PORTRAIT.rawValue

Now, I need to convert that value into 4 bytes.

Thanks.

Comment: bigEndian or littleEndian?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data)

Comment: @LeoDabus, I need both methods incase one way doesn't work

Comment: @Jessy, no I need 4 bytes in both separate bigEndian and littleEndian

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29970204/1187415.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let value: UInt32 = 1
var u32LE = value.littleEndian // or simply value
let dataLE = Data(bytes: &u32LE, count: 4)
let bytesLE = Array(dataLE)  // [1, 0, 0, 0]

var u32BE = value.bigEndian
let dataBE = Data(bytes: &u32BE, count: 4)
let bytesBE = Array(dataBE)  // [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know the property little/big Endian existed!

Comment: Interesting. (voted.) Is there a similar method to littleEndian/bigEndian to get platform specific binary representations of floating point values?

Comment: @DuncanC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502591/convert-a-date-absolute-time-to-be-sent-received-across-the-network-as-data-in/47502712#comment81980820_47502712